# OIDC Logging out issue , How to control the browser programatically/manually?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, openid-connect

I’m using OIDC client in my Xamarin App(*Code below*) So when I make the call `oidcClient.LogoutAsync` browser opens, and while I’m awaiting the response back from the browser to the app if I need to minimise the app for some reason. The call then gets interrupted and the app stays on the browser, Never gives a response back, unless user manually closes the browser. Now I have no control over the browser from my app, Is there a way to avoid this. Maybe not open the browser altogether and logout silently. Please suggest a workaround.

```
private OidcClient InitializeAuthClient()
{
    var options = new OidcClientOptions
    {
        Authority = Config.AuthorityURL,
        ClientId = Config.ClientId,
        Scope = Config.Scope,
        RedirectUri = Config.RedirectUri,
        ClientSecret = Config.ClientSecret,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = Config.RedirectUri,
        Browser = new WebAuthenticatorBrowser(),
    };
    return new OidcClient(options);
}
```

```
OidcClient oidcClient = InitializeAuthClient();
LogoutResult logoutResult = await oidcClient.LogoutAsync(new LogoutRequest 
{ BrowserDisplayMode = IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser.DisplayMode.Hidden, IdTokenHint = authData.idToken });
```

Comment: logging out would require sending the user's browser to a logout URL to clear the cookies

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Yeah, I get that, but when that browser is open and the user receives a call or minimizes the screen, the logout call is somehow interrupted and no callback is triggered, unless the user closes the browser manually, which is a big UX problem.